# What do you need to play gamecube games on your wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, nintendo-gamecube

Which additional accessories are required to be able to play gamecube games on the wii? (besides a Wii and a Gamecube game)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will also need:

- Gamecube Gamepads (nothing else will be detected once you enter GameCube mode. You will have to turn off the Wii to leave the game, for example, like you would on a Gamecube)
- Gamecube memory cards, if you want to save.

Comment: Can you use the classic controller with gamecube games?

Comment: @Neil - when you start a gamecube game, the console enters a "Gamecube mode", and behaves like a gamecube only. Wiimotes are not recognized anymore, only the GC controllers and memory card, and you can't get back to the menu without rebooting.

Comment: @Neil effectively, No, as the classic controller requires the wiimote to operate, which won't be recognized in "Gamecube mode"

Comment: Thanks for the info. I knew wiimotes wouldn't work, but didnt know if Nintendo had built something into the classic controllers to allow them to work in Gamecube mode.

@alex I also wasn't aware that the classic needed a wiimote to work. I guess it transmits it's data via the wiimote?

Comment: @Neil - Yup it is the wiimote that contains all the hardware required for wireless interfacing with the wii itself. (bluetooth) - this is also the reason the classic controller is wired to the wiimote