# Does the Wii still corrupt 1019 GameCube memory cards?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I just bought Eternal Darkness and intend to play it on my Wii.

[I apparently need a GameCube controller and memory card](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/what-do-you-need-to-play-gamecube-games-on-your-wii), so I've done some shopping for a Wavebird (man, [they're expensive](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=videogames&field-keywords=wavebird&x=0&y=0)!) and memory card. [A quick search](http://www.google.com/search?q=wii%201019%20corrupt) reveals that many people have seen their Wii corrupt all their data stored on [1019 GameCube memory cards](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001YYNLM).

Is this still the case? Should I just buy a [251 memory card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00012D0SG) and call it a wrap?

Comment: You can find much less expensive 2nd party wireless GC controllers that work just fine, I own 4.  Also you're in for a good game when you finally get there.  I did a play through of that title a year or two ago when I was applying to Silicon Knights for a job.

Comment: @Stephen - Yeah, I remember playing it on the Cube way back in the day, so I know  I'm in for a treat. Is there a particular brand of 2nd party wireless GC controller that you recommend?

Comment: I will check when I get home, I do recall that the Pelican G3's are terrible.  Using a wired controller with an extension cord actually works well given the amount of actual use you get out of things.

Comment: I played with my 1019 for years. Then in first year I tried it on my roommate's Wii. Corrupted. Maybe it's just hardware

Comment: Yeah, guess I'll just get the 251.  Btw @Stephen, were those wireless controllers Komodos by any chance?

Comment: FYI to passersby, Stack Overflow automatically replaces the links to some products on Amazon with sponsored links. That's not my doing, and you can see as much if you try to edit my post.

Comment: I knew you needed a controller, had no idea you needed a memory card too.  =(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the corruption problem was caused by the hardware, then the Wii will still corrupt those specific GameCube memory cards today, as there have not been any substantial hardware changes to the Wii since release - and the hardware changes that have occurred were primarily to prevent hacking the Wii.

If the corruption problem was caused by software, we don't know if it is fixed or not, as Nintendo has never acknowledged the issue, nor specifically said that a new version of the OS has fixed it.

If you are concerned about it, just buy a different card.

Comment: Data corruption could be caused by a correctable bug in the Wii OS, no?

Comment: Yes, yes it could.  Sorry.  I read through the provided Google search and most of the guesses on the problem related to heat buildup.